# How to use Bootstrap 5 at the same time bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-5

The question summarize it itself.

Currently, I am using bootstrap 3 in my project. I needed the `card` class in the bootstrap 5.

But when I link the bootstrap 5 in my project all objects are disordered. I thinks it's because of same name of the classes. But regardless, How can I achieve this without linking the bootstrap 5 on my project?

Comment: You need to migrate to Bootstrap 5 or write a custom card component manually. You shouldn't and can't mix different versions of Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

it will be complicated when you apply B5 on B3 project, rather create the code manually. cos the classes for B5 and b3 will definitely clash when you link both on the same project

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34676186)